# Missing values in some columns after combining tables using UNION ALL in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on the Google Data Analytics capstone project. I've created 6 tables in big query and am trying to use the UNION ALL function to combine the tables into 1 new table. When I do this, the output shows null values for all rows of 2 of the columns (start_station_id and start_station_name) even though the tables that they were combined from have these values. These columns do contain some null values in the original tables, but not every entry.

All of the columns are in the same location in each original data set and they are all showing up with the same data type when I inspect the schema in bigquery.

Can someone please explain why the output has removed this data from these columns, and what I should be doing instead?

My Code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `essential-truth-371109.bike_tripdata_12months.6_months3` AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM `essential-truth-371109.bike_tripdata_12months.2022_December`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * 
  FROM `essential-truth-371109.bike_tripdata_12months.2022_November`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * 
  FROM `essential-truth-371109.bike_tripdata_12months.2023_April`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * 
  FROM `essential-truth-371109.bike_tripdata_12months.2023_January`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * 
  FROM `essential-truth-371109.bike_tripdata_12months.2023_February`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * 
  FROM `essential-truth-371109.bike_tripdata_12months.2023_March`
```

I was expecting the output to contain both the existing data from each of the original tables as well as any missing/null values included in the originals. Other columns which also have missing values in the original tables have been published as expected.